# Can't install wine on 12.04.2

Tags: wine

I have just done a new install of 12.04.2 I am running an Acer Travelmate 7750G 64 bit with core-i7 processor.

When I try and install wine from the software center, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.4 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4) but it is a virtual package
```

I am a relative Ubuntu newbie when it comes to installing software other than via the software centre, so can anyone perhaps tell me how to go about fixing this?

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

Go here: http://www.winehq.org/download and get your package.
Once you DL it, you can install by using `sudo dpkg <pkgname>` from within the same directory.